# How to convert text into wave

Tags: sound

I am trying to transfer text data via sound wave between two android phones. I am a newbie and would like to know how to proceed with it. I am stuck at the very first step on how to modulate text data as FSK or PCM raw data ? As I shall be implementing it on Android any Java pointers will be of great help

Comment: Sounds a bit too much like writing code to a spec....

Answer (score 3):

Text is just a string of bytes, and each byte is just a string of bits (typically 7 or 8), so the question boils down to: how to I send and receive a string of 1s and 0s using audio ?

You might consider using a simple [AFSK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency-shift_keying#Audio_FSK) scheme, where e.g. a 1 is represented by 2 cycles of a 2400 Hz sine wave and 0 is represented by 1 cycle of a 1200 Hz sine wave. So each bit period is the same length (8.14 ms) and the frequency for that bit period determines whether it's a 1 or a 0. Typically you would use a software [UART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uart) to frame each character and handle the problem of synchronization between transmitter and receiver. This would allow you to send 1 ASCII character in around 10 bit periods. The bit rate is 1200 bps so you would be able to send around 120 characters of uncompressed text per second.